# Kotlin: How to iterate through a collection from a specific position with indexes (skip N elements with indexes)

Tags: kotlin

I want to iterate a collection of items from a specific position.
Let's say we want to start from center and iterate the whole right part of the array:

```
int startFrom = arr.length / 2;
for (int i = startFrom; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    String.format("Index %d value %s", i, arr[i]);
}
```

It's important to track real indexes and values during iteration. As an example you are going to implement in-place sorting algorithm

I've tried to do so using drop().withIndexes(), but looks like drop() creates a new collection and I lose information about real indexes.
It could be fixed manually if we create a variable and calculate proper index

```
val startFrom = inputData.size / 2
for ((i, item) in inputData.drop(startFrom).withIndex()){
    val fixedIndex = i + startFrom
    println("Index $i, fixed index $fixedIndex value $item")
}
```

This solution works but I was hopping there is something that can help to avoid introducing a separate fixedIndex variable and handling this problem manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original try is very close, just a small change makes it work.  Reverse the calls of [`withIndex()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) and [`drop(N)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) putting `withIndex` first.

If you **do not** want to copy the collection, you can convert it to a sequence first using [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html).

```
for ((index, item) in inputData.asSequence().withIndex().drop(startFrom)) { ... }
```

The test code:

```
val sampleData = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
val startFrom = sampleData.size / 2

for ((index, item) in sampleData.asSequence().withIndex().drop(startFrom)) {
    println("[$index] => $item")
}
```

outputs:

> [3] => d
>   [4] => e
>   [5] => f

That's it!  The rest of this answer just provides you with alternatives, including a more efficient and Kotlinesque solution of creating your own extension function at the end.

---

If the copy of the collection is acceptable, you can do the following shorter version.  The `withIndex` does not cause a copy, but the `drop(N)` does.

```
for ((index, item) in inputData.withIndex().drop(startFrom)) { ... }
```

The eager copy *or* the sequence could be faster, it depends on the size of the collection, your runtime environment, and CPU cache.

You can also use functional [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) instead of the `for` loop.

```
sampleData.asSequence().withIndex().drop(startFrom).forEach { (index, item) ->
    println("[$index] => $item")       
}
```

**Which then brings up the best and most efficient option.**  Just write an extension function when using an `Array` or `List` so that there is no lazy evaluation using wrapper classes nor any copying.  Simply a loop calling your lambda with the index and value.  Here are the two new extensions that add a new variation of `forEachIndexed`:

```
inline fun <T> Array<T>.forEachIndexed(startFrom: Int, 
                                action: (index: Int, item: T)->Unit) {
    for (i in startFrom until this.size) {
        action(i, this[i])
    }
}

inline fun <T> List<T>.forEachIndexed(startFrom: Int, 
                               action: (index: Int, item: T)->Unit) {
    for (i in startFrom until this.size) {
        action(i, this[i])
    }
}
```

And this can be called simply for any non-primitive array or list:

```
sampleData.forEachIndexed(startFrom) { index, item ->
    println("[$index] => $item")
}
```

You could do the same if you want a `withIndex(startFrom)` style method as well.  You can always extend Kotlin to get what you want!

Comment: Thank you Jason, it's brilliant!
I haven't even thought that withIndex() on the first place is legit.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you're missing, the simplest solution in my opinion is to just use a ranged `for` loop:

```
val startFrom = arr.size / 2;
for (i in startFrom until arr.size) {
    println(String.format("Index %d value %s", i, arr[i]));
}
```

If you prefer strictly avoiding expressions like `arr[i]`, then you can change your current solution to use a sequence instead.